# Open external links in webview as default in IOS PWA

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm testing Progressive Web App in IOS 11.3.

My pwa has a Facebook social login button that, when clicked, points to an external link (different windows.location).

The problem is that the pwa opens safari app to show external links instead of using a webview within the pwa. So, when the login is done, you will not be redirected to the pwa, but remains in safari.

I tried following examples like this one:  https://gist.github.com/kylebarrow/1042026 but seems not working

How can I force the pwa to open external links in a webview?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This problem is solved in IOS 11.4

**UPDATE**

@twhite96 @Marty121 The Google Social login worked well few times but now seems to be broken again :/ The offline support seems to be broken too! PWA on IOS sucks!
I think we need to wait the next IOS release hoping that they will fix the long list of bugs

Comment: I am still having this issue in iOS 11.4, final release. Does installing the 11.4.1 beta help at all?

Comment: @twhite96 I'm using Facebook\Google login in my app and updating IOS to 11.4 solved my problem at all. I hope of course that in the next IOS releases they will improve more the pwa

Comment: @Enricosoft What does your manifest.json file look like? Specifically, the “scope” property?

Comment: @Enricosoft I'm using GitHub as oauth on Spectrum chat and The Practical Dev. Tried Twitter as well. Broken. Installed 11.4.1 and filed a bug report.

Answer (score 2):

Use BUTTON instead of A tag and set onclick with window.location.href = 'yourUrl'
It seems to working well

Comment: It did not work for me. It still opens a new window in iOS 12

Answer (score 2):

If you use SSR (Server Side Rendering) and your PWA is not static, you should follow App Shell concept. So every time when you click external link, it should be fetched and inserted in your dynamic section.
Link: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/11/app-shell