# Progressive Web App problem with social login

Tags: javascript, ios, web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App that is on 'standalone' mode and it has email, facebook and google logins. The app works perfectly for android and desktop but when I add the app to my home page on iOS and I try to login with Facebook or Google, it opens in safari and accepts the account and then just stays on a blank page without redirecting to the app (not even on Safari)

I already tried 'pwacompat' but it broke other stuff on my app, it would accept google or facebook on standalone but it broke email login and other buttons on my app.

This is the code that is on the head of my app

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest">
```

and my manifest looks like this

```
                    "scope": ".",
                    "theme_color": "#000000",
                    "background_color": primaryColor,
                    "display": "standalone",
                    "orientation": "portrait-primary"
```

I want to be able to log in via FB or Google on standalone and if that's not possible, then I want people to be able to use it in safari once redirected there through the app. Meaning that when you click FB or Google button it will take you to safari and it will not stay blank, it will open the app there.

Comment: Have you tried the solution accepted in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503158/open-external-links-in-webview-as-default-in-ios-pwa)?